# Error while creating list of template TreeNodes

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <typename T>
class BST
{
private:
    class TreeNode
    {
    public:
        T data;
        TreeNode *left;
        TreeNode *right;
        TreeNode(const T & d, TreeNode *lchld = NULL, TreeNode *rchld = NULL):
            data(d), left(lchld), right(rchld) {}
    };

    TreeNode *root;
    vector<list<TreeNode *> *> createLevelLinkedList(TreeNode *root);
public:
};

template <typename T>
vector< list< typename BST<T>::TreeNode *> *> BST<T>::createLevelLinkedList(TreeNode *root)
{
    vector<list<BST<T>::TreeNode *> *> result;
    if (root == NULL) return result;
    list<TreeNode *> *treeNodeList = new list<TreeNode *>();
    int level = 0;

    treeNodeList->push_back(root);
    result[0] = treeNodeList;

    while(true) {
        treeNodeList = new list<TreeNode *>();
        list<TreeNode *>::iterator itr;

        for( itr = (result[level])->begin(); itr != (result[level])->end(); itr++)
        {
            TreeNode *temp = *itr;
            if( temp != NULL)
            {
                if(temp->right != NULL) treeNodeList->push_back(temp->right);
                if(temp->left  != NULL) treeNodeList->push_back(temp->left);
            }
        }

        if(treeNodeList->size() > 0)
        {
            result[level++] = treeNodeList;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am trying to compile the above code but getting compilation error with following lines of code:

```
list<TreeNode *>::iterator itr;
```

The error say the following:

Multiple markers at this line
    - need 'typename' before 'std::list::TreeNode*>::iterator' because 
     'std::list::TreeNode*>' is a dependent scope
    - expected ';' before 'itr'

I tried various options but nothing seems to be working. If I compile a non template based code, it works but i want to compile this template based code. Can someone help me to find problem and suggest me way/ways to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just follow the error

> Multiple markers at this line - **need 'typename' before '`std::list::<TreeNode*>::iterator`'** because '`std::list::<TreeNode*>`' is a dependent scope - expected ';' before 'itr'

You wrote:

```
list<TreeNode*>::iterator itr;
```

You need to write:

```
typename list<TreeNode*>::iterator itr;
```

The reason for that is the compiler doesn't know at this point whether `list<TreeNode*>::iterator` is a nested type or a member variable, so you have to tell it. Who knows, there might be a specialization of `list<TreeNode*>` somewhere else that defines `iterator` to be a member! This is known as **dependent scope** because what `iterator` means *depends* on the instantiation of `list<TreeNode*>`.

Comment: Thanks. It does work although I am still not very clear with explanation. Is there any link where i can read this in more detail?

Comment: @user489703 Try [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name)